# Read from LDAP based on ObjectGUID with PHP

Tags: php, filter, active-directory, ldap, guid

I've created a web based administration system for our AD environment. I'm having issues currently trying to read directory entries based on objectguid. Is this possible to do?

I'm able to do something like:

```
$filter = "(&(objectclass=*)(objectguid=$objectguid))";
$search = ldap_read($ds, $dn, $filter);
```

With the $dn being something like CN=Test,OU=Group,DC=OCJ,DC=Domain,DC=Com. So I know it's accepting the guid, but I'd like to skip the $dn part, reading with ONLY the GUID.

Any suggestions? I can't find anything saying that [`ldap_read`](http://php.net/ldap_read) can read directly with GUID.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To read only the guid, give the third parameters that controls what attributes you want returned. The second $dn parameter is mandatory, it specifies the search scope, and you can always set it to the root_dn if you want to be less specific.

If you want no dn entries in the result set array, that is not possible directly as this is the API of the ldap_read function, but you can filter them out by traversing the array (map).

```
$search = ldap_read($ds, $root_dn, $filter, array('objectguid'));
```

Comment: As stated, I've already got the GUID. I'm trying to read entries based on the guid alone, without a full DN or only giving a extreme base DN. So, DC=OCJ,DC=Domain,DC=Com and filtering by guid (which gives me nothing), but getting all attributes.

Comment: I got it. I used ldap_search instead of ldap_read. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

You can bind by GUID also. Set your $dn to `<GUID={guid-goes-here}>`

Comment: Fixed - apparently the site was not displaying the stuff in angle brackets until I escaped it.